# Python convert value from int to string into array dictionary

Tags: python

i have a specific array dictionary that have a specific int value.
This is an example:

```
res = [{'number': 2, 'm': '13520'}, {'number': 17, 'm': '13518'}]
```

how i can convert the value of number key, from int to string?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have a value, you can just call `str(value)`. We're not here to program for you ;)

Comment: This dictionary is a response of a request and i need to use it as result into a function, but converting the key number into a string

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop will work for in place modification:

```
res = [{'number': 2, 'm': '13520'}, {'number': 17, 'm': '13518'}]

for d in res:
    if 'number' in d:
        d['number'] = str(d['number'])
```

output:

```
[{'number': '2', 'm': '13520'}, {'number': '17', 'm': '13518'}]
```